# clear method in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a clear method that would clear the array I have, I've seen that using a clear method is what I need but I cannot seem to use it?

```
 list.clear();
```

What I think I have to do:

```
public void clear() {
        return doctors.clear();
    }
```

doctors are an array by the way.

However I think I am thinking about this incorrectly..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `array` is not a `List`.  There is no `clear` method.  You can clear one by assigning a null reference, and let the garbage collector take care of it...

`yourArray = null;`

or create a new array, and replace the old with the new.  The old one will be garbage collected.

`yourArray = new YourObject[n];`

Comment: How would one assign a null refrence?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply create a new empty array and assign that:

```
doctors = new Doctor[size];
```

The array will be defined but the objects will not be created yet.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you want to make it a null reference, have size 0, or make all the values = null.

For an array, such as Doctor[], here are some alternatives - not sure which one is applicable for your circumstance...

```
// setting the array to null
doctors = null;

// removing all array entries, making an array of size 0
doctors = new Doctor[0];

// keeping the array the same size, but making all values = null
doctors = new Doctor[doctors.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array, you need to reinitialize it.

```
publiv void clear() {
    this.doctors = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = null
```

or

```
list = new int[list.length];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void clearArray(Object[] Array){
    if (Array==null){
        return;
    }
    for (Object ob: Array){
         ob=null;
    }
}
```